# Making a service from the project

Tags: server, services, init.d

Hi I have a java server(it listens) which runs when I do:
ant compile jar run in the terminal

What I want to do is
sudo service myproject start so that I won't have to be in terminal(when I do ctrl+c in terminal or close the terminal the program stops which I don't want)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to `nohup` the command. This allows you to close the terminal and even log out while the program continues to run.

```
nohup ant compile jar run &
```

This doesn't create a proper 'service' but it does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache Commons Daemon and JSVC: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

It is the solution which is also used by the most common Java daemon: Apache Tomcat.

Comment: There is nothing like where I put a command ant compile jar run and it pass location where to be executed and it will execute it when I do sudo service myapp start?

Comment: Yes it does that, please read the JSVC documentation.